# How to enable Bean Validation with Jax RS in TomEE 7.0.0-M1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, bean-validation, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I'm aware I must be missing some really basic point.
The following resource method:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public TestObject getObj(@QueryParam("m") String m,
                         @Min(30) @NotNull @QueryParam("d") Double d) {
    return new TestObject(m,m,d);
}
```

works as expected in Glassfish4 (i.e returns a 400 Bad Request), but in TomEE 7.0.0-M1 (jee7) it ignores validation annotations, and responds with 200 OK.
I tried setting the property (although in TomEE 7 it is set to be enabled by default), still nothing.

```
org.apache.openejb.default.system.interceptors = org.apache.openejb.bval.BeanValidationAppendixInterceptor
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Having set that property, OR using TomEE 7.0-M1 should have done the trick. Your problem must be in some other place.

Comment: That's what I was hoping... Still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

In M1 I think you need to add @ValidateOnExecution on the method, last releases got it fixed IIRC

Answer (score -1):

You have to add @Singleton or @Stateless annotation in the JAX-RS resource for the bean validations to happen. In the case of CXF for non Singleton/non EJB resources  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInvoker needs to be registered if these objects need to be validated.